# error when trying to run lambda locally using docker with wsl2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, wsl-2, aws-sam-cli

Trying to get AWS SAM CLI working to locally test lambda functions. I've installed the helloworld python function, which I can successfully build and validate, until I add the `--use-container` flag, at which point I get the below errors.

I have Docker Desktop installed and running. I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 on a windows 11 machine.

```
 mylaptop:~/projects/lambda/lambda-python3.8$ sam build --use-container
Starting Build inside a container
Your template contains a resource with logical ID "ServerlessRestApi", which is a reserved logical ID in AWS SAM. It could result in unexpected behaviors and is not recommended.
Building codeuri: /home/projects/lambda/lambda-python3.8/hello_world runtime: python3.8 metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldFunction
<3>init: (15570) ERROR: UtilConnectUnix:467: connect failed 111
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/credentials/store.py", line 80, in _execute
  File "subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 512, in run
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe', 'get']' returned non-zero exit status 255.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/auth.py", line 264, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "docker/credentials/store.py", line 35, in get
  File "docker/credentials/store.py", line 93, in _execute
docker.credentials.errors.StoreError: Credentials store docker-credential-desktop.exe exited with "".

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "samcli/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
  File "click/core.py", line 782, in main
  File "click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
  File "click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
  File "click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 166, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 124, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 41, in wrapped
  File "samcli/cli/main.py", line 87, in wrapper
  File "samcli/commands/build/command.py", line 201, in cli
  File "samcli/commands/build/command.py", line 262, in do_cli
  File "samcli/commands/build/build_context.py", line 248, in run
  File "samcli/lib/build/app_builder.py", line 221, in build
  File "samcli/lib/build/build_strategy.py", line 79, in build
  File "samcli/lib/build/build_strategy.py", line 89, in _build_functions
  File "samcli/lib/build/build_strategy.py", line 171, in build_single_function_definition
  File "samcli/lib/build/app_builder.py", line 654, in _build_function
  File "samcli/lib/build/app_builder.py", line 819, in _build_function_on_container
  File "samcli/local/docker/manager.py", line 115, in run
  File "samcli/local/docker/manager.py", line 85, in create
  File "samcli/local/docker/manager.py", line 160, in pull_image
  File "docker/api/image.py", line 396, in pull
  File "docker/auth.py", line 48, in get_config_header
  File "docker/auth.py", line 324, in resolve_authconfig
  File "docker/auth.py", line 235, in resolve_authconfig
  File "docker/auth.py", line 281, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-desktop.exe exited with "".')
[15567] Failed to execute script __main__
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I ran `docker-credential-desktop.exe version` which resulted in the 111 error message, so I was able to isolate the issue to something related to docker-desktop-credential.exe. After googling around and trying lots of different suggestions, this finally worked for me, without any restart required.

`mv ~/.docker ~/.docker_old`